# How to round this result in SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql, rounding

I need a method to round the result returned from the following statement:

```
CASE 
    WHEN 0 <> (sod.XDFFLT - sod.DUEQTY)
        THEN (sod.XDFFLT - sod.DUEQTY)
    ELSE ''
    END AS Balance
```

Which resides in this SELECT statement.

```
SELECT TOP (10000) som.ORDNUM
    ,som.NAME
    ,som.ADDR1
    ,som.ADDR2
    ,som.CITY
    ,som.STATE
    ,som.ZIPCD
    ,som.CNTRY
    ,som.CUSTPO
    ,COALESCE(cpd.CUSTPRT, sod.PRTNUM) AS CustomerSku
    ,cpd.CUSTPRT
    ,som.CUSTID
    ,sod.PRTNUM
    ,ps.PMDES1
    ,sod.CURQTY
    ,sod.DUEQTY
    ,sod.XDFFLT
    ,sod.SHPQTY
    ,CASE 
        WHEN 0 <> (sod.XDFFLT - sod.DUEQTY)
            THEN (sod.XDFFLT - sod.DUEQTY)
        ELSE ''
        END AS Balance
    ,sod.LINNUM + sod.DELNUM AS LineDelNum
    ,CASE 
        WHEN 12 <= len(sod.UDFREF)
            THEN substring(sod.UDFREF, 9, 4)
        ELSE sod.UDFREF
        END AS Skid
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: `DBMS` looks like **SQL Server**, but the query is missing `FROM` section.

Comment: What do you mean by round ? Here i don't see any rounding. Your case statement and `(sod.XDFFLT - sod.DUEQTY)` are equal. When the `(sod.XDFFLT - sod.DUEQTY) = 0` the `''` will be converted to `0`

Comment: Why are you assigning a string value, albeit empty, to what is in fact a numeric column in the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the CASE with this:

```
,CASE 
    WHEN 0 <> (sod.XDFFLT - sod.DUEQTY)
        THEN ROUND((sod.XDFFLT - sod.DUEQTY), <number_of_decimals>)
    ELSE NULL
    END AS Balance
```

Make sure to replace the `<number_of_decimlas>` with the appropriate number of decimals you want the number to be rounded to.

- greater than 0 will return a number which is rounded on the right side of the comma (decimal point)
- less than 0 will return a number which is rounded on the left side of the comma (decimal point)

Also, **don't use a blank string** in the `ELSE` clause of your case since this will cause a datatype missmatch and generate an error (a `CASE` must return a **single** datatype). Hence, it is better to replace this with `NULL`, since your first condition will always return a number.

Comment: Oracle will treat an empty string `''` as `NULL` but generally you are right, `NULL` would be the better choice.